# How does @OnetoOne relationship work in JPA?

Tags: spring, jpa, one-to-one

I am trying to establish one to one mapping between two entities. One entity maintains user records as follows:

```
@Entity
public class ConcreteUser implements User{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private int age;
    private SEX sex;
    private String accessLevel;

    public ConcreteUser() {
    }

    public ConcreteUser(String name, String email, int age, SEX sex, String accessLevel) {
        // set class properties
    }

   //
   // Some getter and setter code
   //
```

I want to use the primary key from the above entity as a foreign key in other entity, which maintains other information. Here's what the other entity looks like:

```
@Entity
public class SomeOtherEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "SOME_COLUMN_NAME")
    private long recordId;

    //
    // some other private fields here
    //

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private ConcreteUser concreteUser;

    public SomeOtherEntity () {
    }

    // getters and setters etc
```

My sample test case is as follows:

```
@Test
public void testAddSomeOtherEntity() throws Exception {


    /* This is the user, whose primary key will be used as a foreign key in SomeOtherEntity */
    ConcreteUser user = new ConcreteUser(...);


    /* Create a new SomeOtherEntity and assign a ConcreteUser to it */
    SomeOtherEntity d = new SomeOtherEntity();
    d.setConcreteUser(user); /* I doubt if this line has any effect at all */

    // add SomeOtherEntity to table
    /* addSomeOtherEntity is translated to an HTTP request and server responds with added entity  */
    d = myService.addSomeOtherEntity(d); 
    assertNotNull(d);

    /* At this point, the recordId is generated and updated */

    // Check if this entity was added properly
    long recordId = d.getRecordId();
    SomeOtherEntity d2 = myService.getSomeOtherEntityById(recordId);
    assertNotNull(d2);

    /* This test case passes */
    assertEquals(d2.getRecordId(), d.getRecordId()); 

    /* But this test case fails */
    assertEquals(d2.getConcreteUser().getId(), d.getConcreteUser().getId());

}
```

In summary, I create SomeOtherEntity object, assign a ConcreteUser object and persist SomeOtherEntity . However, when I retrieve SomeOtherEntity back, I get a different ConcreteUser than what I had assigned earlier. In particular, the ConcreteUser that I get back, is the one that has same "id", as that of "recordId". This is not what I was expecting.

I am quite new to Spring and I am sure I have misunderstood something. As of now, I am thinking assigning ConcreteUser to SomeOtherEntity in advance means nothing. Instead, maybe I should create and persist SomeOtherEntity first and then update the ConcreteUser?
I'd really appreciate if someone could offer some advice and how it's done in real world. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your SomeOtherEntity you specify @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn mapping for ConcreteUser. If you check [the documentation of the annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/PrimaryKeyJoinColumn.html), you find out that it says:

> ... and it may be used in a OneToOne mapping in which the primary key of
>   the referencing entity is used as a foreign key to the referenced
>   entity

That means that primary key value of SomeOtherEntity is used as foreign key value to the ConcreteUser.

You want to use [@JoinColumn](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html) annotation instead.

Comment: He mightn't event need the `@JoinColumn` annotation at all.

Answer (score 0):

So, as it turns out, there are different ways to implement one to one relationship in Spring. Following is a short and useful introduction to different ways:
[Hibernate one-to-one mapping using annotations](http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/11/15/hibernate-one-to-one-mapping-using-annotations/)

The issue here was not the owning side, but the method chosen for one to one mapping out of the three. As per the article mentioned above, `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` annotation is used when you want the primary keys of two tables to match, which is not really the case here.
As mentioned in the question, test cases failed because Hibernate mapped two tables based on the primary key and not by what `ConcreteUser` entity was assigned using `setConcreteUser`